# xmlstarlet Remove nodes with duplicate attributes

Tags: xml, xpath, xmlstarlet

I am trying to delete duplicate entries in an `xml` file based on the value of an attribute.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<root>
  <entries>
    <entry name="entry1">
      <value>1</value>
    </entry>
    <entry name="entry1">     <-- Duplicate name here
      <value>2</value>
    </entry>
    <entry name="entry2">
      <value>3</value>
    </entry>
  </entries>
</root>
```

And I want the following

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<root>
  <entries>
    <entry name="entry1">
      <value>1</value>
    </entry>
    <entry name="entry2">
      <value>3</value>
    </entry>
  </entries>
</root>
```

I have tried

```
xmlstarlet edit --delete '/_:root/_:entries/*[@name = .//preceding-sibling::*/@name]'
```

But the `xpath` does not match the previous entry with the attribute `name="entry1"`

Comment: Are duplicate entries always one immediately after each other, or can they be separated by non-duplicated entries?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use the YAML processor [mikefarah/yq](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/), your task can be solved in this way:

**Version < 4.30**

`yq --input-format xml --output-format xml e '.root.entries.entry |= unique_by(.+name)'`

**Version >= 4.30**

`yq --input-format xml --output-format xml e '.root.entries.entry |= unique_by(.+@name)'`

**Output**

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<root>
  <entries>
    <entry name="entry1">
      <value>1</value>
    </entry>
    <entry name="entry2">
      <value>3</value>
    </entry>
  </entries>
</root>
```

This solution has the benefit that the order of the elements in the array is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove the `.//` from the `preceding-sibling::`.

Like this:

```
xmlstarlet edit --delete '/_:root/_:entries/*[@name = preceding-sibling::*/@name]' input.xml
```

Note: I tested this but needed to add a default namespace to the XML so that the `_` namespace prefix would work. If you don't have a default namespace in your actual input, remove the `_:` from your xpath.